# How to select features for a machine learning regression problem

Tags: regression, machine-learning, feature-selection, nonlinear-regression

This may seem like a noob question but for a machine learning regression problem, how do we select features for a machine learning regression problem?

Background: The problem I am working on has about 190 features and only some of these features are linearly related to my output. Then the logical option would be to choose only the linearly related features for prediction.

*But,*

these same features are also highly correlated with each other. I read that features which are correlated are usually removed to improve training speed and increase the generalization capability (https://towardsdatascience.com/a-feature-selection-tool-for-machine-learning-in-python-b64dd23710f0). So far the only algorithms I have seen for regression problems include simple Linear Regression, LassoCV, RidgeCV and these require a linear relationship with the output so I am confused as to which features to select.

So coming back to my question, Can someone please explain how they go about selecting features for a machine learning regression problem?

Also, what algorithms are usually used for Regression problems? I have read about LassoCV, ElasticNetCV, DecisionTreeRegressor but I would like to know if there is anything else I am missing.

Comment: Feature selection is a large topic. How to go about solving it depends on what problem you're trying to solve, and what level of complexity you want to bring to bear on the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are many methods to do feature selection in ML. Related to your problem, first remove the correlation among features in your dataset. Also, just selecting those features which are linearly dependent on the target variable is ill advised. The idea in ML is to use every bit of information related to the problem which could have linear or non-linear relation with the target variable. You should focus on non-linear methods for model selection.
Refer to this resource : https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/12/introduction-to-feature-selection-methods-with-an-example-or-how-to-select-the-right-variables/

Comment: Thank you, I checked the link out! I will try using the wrapper methods to select features

Comment: I'm glad it was useful to you. Cheers!